# Node.js works with CouchDB and Backbone.js, How json is being served?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, couchdb, express, cradle

I am trying to build a test app for learning Node.js. I came from wordpress background and Apache has setup most of backend logics for me. But now, I have to build my own. I have a question about how to serve JSON files from server side to client side. What is the workflow -- Backbone.js handle all client side Data manipulation, send/save/get/fetch from couchDB, serve JSON object from NODE.js backend?

I am using [Express Microframework](http://expressjs.com/) for building HTTP server, installed the Cradle middleware for access CouchDB NoSQL database. I successfully posted the data from Client side HTML (Jade template engine) to the CouchDB Database/Document and able to retrieve those data back from Server through Cradle middleware. Things work out great. But it was all done by Backend.

I want to use Backbone.js for my client side Javascript. Backbone.js is looking for JSON object which send back from the HTTP server. Cradle Middleware is able to create JSON object but only send them directly to the Jade Template, I could use Jade syntax for loop to iterate over the data object but it still not meet what I want for Backbone.js handle all the data entry. I realize that I need to get JSON obj via ajax ( either a file generated by HTTP then send back to the client  OR   send straight object to the client ). Cradle Middleware could not do that.

I did more research on this questions. I tried [CouchApp](http://couchapp.org/page/index), it does what I need. Using the Backbone.js to handling all the data, send/save/fetch data from CouchDB database. But it is a running in CouchApp, it is not an Express Node.js workflow. ( Maybe I am wrong or just do not how it work )

I tried [backbone-couchdb.js](http://janmonschke.com/projects/backbone-couchdb.html). I read through the Details and still do not know it is going to help me to get what I want.  ( Maybe need more tutorial or code example ). I am still thinking that I need a Backbone CouchDB driver to connect those two and somehow serving them by NODE.js backend.

Is there anybody who could tell me about how JSON file is being served by Node.js, how backbone.js interact with data save/fetch/get from CouchDB? What is the best practice / workflow? Other good resources, code examples, useful tools?

Comment: I think you are thinking everything wrong. You are picking tools instead of focusing on solving the problem in hand.

Answer (score 1):

> Cradle Middleware is able to create JSON object but only send them directly to the Jade Template

This is incorrect. You can just send the json back without rendering a template.

```
function(req, res, next){
  db.view('user/byUsername', { key: 'luke' }, function (err, doc) {
    res.send(doc); // or res.json(doc);
  });
}
```

Comment: Do I still need any Backbone Drivers at all or anything else? Sounds like the Cradle would take care of all.  Could you also describe what is the best/popular workflow ( Node.js - CouchDB - Backbone.js  == Server - DB - Client )

Comment: It all depends what you want. There are some integrated solutions like the one you linked (backbone-coucdb). If you use that you don't need a middle tier. If you don't want to use a middle tier you can do normal ajax requests to the server to retrieve data. This is probably the most basic way of doing it.

Comment: Sounds like they both works for data manipulation. Is there any tutorials or Resources or code examples out there that I can check it out? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems you are missing some general knowledge. I would first start with either learning backbone and then learn some basic Node.js + Express.js. I don't know any tutorial of the top of my head but considering how popular both technologies are Google should give you some good results.

Comment: @MMA: I found webcasts in PluralSight.com about Node.js and Backbone.js useful. If you pay full membership, you can also download code.